Eslint Migrate to v9.x, how to setup parserOptions.project for @typescript-eslint/parser while loading rule @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports
When I run with the following configuration to migrate from version 8 to version 9 get an error. I want to know where the problem is .
the error:

Oops! Something went wrong! :(
ESLint: 9.1.0
Error: Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports': You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated. You must therefore provide a value for the "parserOptions.project" property for @typescript-eslint/parser.
Parser: undefined
Note: detected a parser other than @typescript-eslint/parser. Make sure the parser is configured to forward "parserOptions.project" to @typescript-eslint/parser.
....

I tried adding the following configuration but it doesn't seem to work
      {
        files: ['*.vue'],
        parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
        parserOptions: {
          parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
          project: './tsconfig.json',
          extraFileExtensions: ['.vue'],
          ecmaVersion: 'latest',
          ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true,
          },
        },
        rules: {
          'no-undef': 'off',
        },
      },

the configuration files :
eslint.config.js
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import path from 'path'
import { FlatCompat } from '@eslint/eslintrc'
import js from '@eslint/js'
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';
import markdown from 'eslint-plugin-markdown'
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)

console.log(path.resolve('.', './tsconfig.json'))  
// /Users/xxxx-rd/repo/vue3-works/internal/eslintlib/tsconfig.json


const compat = new FlatCompat({
  baseDirectory: __dirname,
  resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
  recommendedConfig: js.configs.recommended,
})

export default [
  ...markdown.configs.recommended,
  {
    ignores: ['dist', '**/*.d.ts'],
  },
  ...compat.config({
    env: {
      node: true,
      browser: true,
      es2022: true,
    },
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'eslint-plugin-tsdoc', 'unicorn'],
    extends: [
      'eslint:recommended',
      'plugin:import/recommended',
      'plugin:eslint-comments/recommended',
      'plugin:jsonc/recommended-with-jsonc',
      'plugin:vue/recommended',
      'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    ],
    parserOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    },
    settings: {
      'import/resolver': {
        node: {
          extensions: ['.js', 'mjs', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'],
        },
      },
    },
    overrides: [
      {
        files: ['*.json', '*.json5', '*.jsonc'],
        parser: 'jsonc-eslint-parser',
      },

      {
        files: ['*.vue'],
        parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
        parserOptions: {
          parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
          project: './tsconfig.json',
          extraFileExtensions: ['.vue'],
          ecmaVersion: 'latest',
          ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true,
          },
        },
        rules: {
          'no-undef': 'off',
        },
      },
    ],
    rules: {
      '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-asserted-optional-chain': 'off',
      '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports': ['error', { disallowTypeAnnotations: false }],
      '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': ['off', { 'ts-ignore': false }],
      '@typescript-eslint/ban-types': [
        'error',
        {
          extendDefaults: true,
          types: {
            '{}': false,
          },
        },
      ],

      'import/default': 'off',
      'import/no-named-as-default': 'off',
      'import/no-named-as-default-member': 'off',
    },
  }),
]

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src","**/*.config.ts", "**/*.config.js"]
}

package.json
{
  "name": "@eslint9",
  "private": false,
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/umd/index.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/es/index.mjs",
  "types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    "types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts",
    "import": "./dist/es/index.mjs",
    "require": "./dist/umd/index.umd.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.9.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.9.0",
    "eslint": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsonc": "^2.15.1",
    "eslint-plugin-markdown": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-tsdoc": "^0.2.17",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^53.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.25.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "typescript-eslint": "^7.8.0",
    "vite": "^5.2.10",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "^3.9.0",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1"
  }
}

Thanks in advance .
